# Is there a closed form for this logarthmic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following expression that I am looking to simplify.

Note that $n$ is a power of 2, that is, $n = 2^i$ for all $i \leq log_2(n)$

I would like to simplify:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{i-1} \lfloor log_2(\frac{n}{2^k}) \rfloor $$

I am not sure how to go about finding a closed form for this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see why we have $i\le\log_2(n)$ when we actually have $i=\log_2(n)$.

Comment: Well, assuming what your wrote is correct (I'm not sure what that inequality is doing on the second line), we first note that $\log_2(\frac{n}{2^k})=\log_2(2^i)-\log_2(2^k)=i-k$

Comment: Please note that you say 2 things that don't make much sense together. You say $n = 2^i $ for all $i < log_2(n) $... either thing you say depends on the other. Check that please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log_2(\frac n{2^k})=\log_2(\frac{2^i}{2^k})=\log_2(2^{i-k})=i-k$

Since $i,k$ are whole numbers, we have $\lfloor i-k\rfloor=i-k$.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\lfloor\log_2(\frac n{2^k})\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}\lfloor i-k\rfloor=\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}(i-k)=i^2-\frac{i(i-1)}2=\frac{i^2+i}2$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll presume that the inequality on the second line doesn't exist, because it makes no sense given the equality right before it. We then have that $$\log_2(\frac{n}{2^k})=\log_2(2^i)-\log_2(2^k)=i-k$$
As such, after noting that this subtraction will always be a whole number you want the sum
$$i^2-\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}  k$$
I leave the rest of the work to the OP, as the question doesn't even seem correct as stated.